# How to run a script at Cygwin shell exit?

Tags: shell, command, cygwin, exit

In Cygwin, my .bash_profile looks like this:

```
nohup mintty &
exit
```

The mintty command fires up and processes all of my *real* startup stuff with .bashrc. What I'd like to do is have all `ssh-agent` processes killed when I exit mintty. Is there a way for me to make this happen automatically?

Answer (score 0):

This may help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup#Overcoming_hanging

(interesting problem, I'd expect that shell exists automatically and leave your process running until finished)